# How to handle multi-window in browsers on Android7

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

Android has a new feature "multi-window" that allow to user view a couple of apps on screen in one time.

As web developer I want to know that my app runs in multi-window mode.

Does browsers (chrome and native android-web-wiew) provides any api for multi-window mode? And how I can handle it?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or provide any other **off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: I would imagine any such API would be implemented the same way as it would for desktop browsers. After all, desktop Web browsers have been able to show the same site in multiple windows since the invention of the Web browser.